# Flutter: Let the Text in Text widget overflow on new line

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a Text widget where I put some text in (title of games), but some game titles hit the max width of the screen (`A RenderFlex overflowed by 77 pixels on the right.` for example). How can I put that the text just continues underneath?

Issue:

[image]

I want to have it like this:

```
|Im a very long title |
|that does not fit.   |
```

EDIT:

The `Text` widget is in a `Row` Widget which exists in a `Column` Widget.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    SomeOtherWidget(),
    Expanded( // add this
      child: Text(
        "This is a long text",
        maxLines: 2, // you can change it accordingly
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // and this
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Wrap your `Text` in `Expanded` and set `overflow` property.

Comment: This did it! Thanks.